# Problem using make_column_transformer in Sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

This is my code/model that I'm trying to implement:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True,random_state=2652124) 

transf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',max_features=1500, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stop)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
metadados = ['F13','F14','F19','F21','F22']
cls = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,random_state=0)


features = make_column_transformer(
                            (transf,'textimage'),(transf,'subtitle'),
                            (scaler, metadata),(scaler,'F3'),remainder ='drop')


X = features.fit_transform(data)
y = data['classification']


for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    cls.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_score = cls.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
    roc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score[:,1])
    pred = cls.predict(X_test)
    acs = accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
    clr = classification_report(y_test,pred)
```

The error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6bdcb91ff478> in <module>
     14 
     15 kfnum = 1
---> 16 X = features.fit_transform(data)
     17 y = data['classe']
     18 catr = 'timagem  + metadados + legenda'

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    529         self._validate_remainder(X)
    530 
--> 531         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    532 
    533         if not result:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    456             self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True))
    457         try:
--> 458             return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    459                 delayed(func)(
    460                     transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1049                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1050 
-> 1051             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1052                 pass
   1053 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    864                 return False
    865             else:
--> 866                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    867                 return True
    868 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    782         with self._lock:
    783             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 784             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    785             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    786             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    738     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    739         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 740             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    741         else:
    742             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    688         if y is None:
    689             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 690             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    691         else:
    692             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    334         # Reset internal state before fitting
    335         self._reset()
--> 336         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    337 
    338     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    367 
    368         first_pass = not hasattr(self, 'n_samples_seen_')
--> 369         X = self._validate_data(X, reset=first_pass,
    370                                 estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
    371                                 force_all_finite="allow-nan")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    418                     f"requires y to be passed, but the target y is None."
    419                 )
--> 420             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    421             out = X
    422         else:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    795               dtype='datetime64[ns]')
    796         """
--> 797         return np.asarray(self.array, dtype)
    798 
    799     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/numpy_.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    209 
    210     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
--> 211         return np.asarray(self._ndarray, dtype=dtype)
    212 
    213     _HANDLED_TYPES = (np.ndarray, numbers.Number)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have no problemas using only:

```
features = make_column_transformer(
                            (transf,'textimage'),(transf,'subtitle'),
                            (scaler, metadata),remainder ='drop')
```

So my problem is the column 'F3' in my dataframe, which is an array in each row:

```
0       [0.0026778684, 0.003117677, 0.00040434036, 0.0...
1       [0.061992627, 0.047432333, 0.012270351, 0.0102...
2       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.3830705e-06, 1.3149212e-05, ...
3       [0.30314153, 0.04477268, 0.01840577, 0.0319251...
4       [0.2563626, 0.03259786, 0.018686974, 0.0198365...
                              ...                        
1287    [0.11471527, 0.032394826, 0.012400794, 0.01131...
1288    [0.002138354, 0.001044489, 0.0007786191, 0.001...
1289    [0.056204572, 0.026556363, 0.02082041, 0.01966...
1290    [0.051759016, 0.0058623934, 0.0054726205, 0.00...
1291    [0.0, 5.4140626e-05, 4.4114586e-05, 4.8125003e...
Name: F3, Length: 1292, dtype: object
```

Can anyone help me with that? How can I change a column into a list into a pipeline, or how can I concatenate the tranform with a list? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please refer to guidelines for posting a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is not reproducible for someone to try and help you. You need to give sample `X_train` if someone else is to reproduce your issue. I would also suggest adding the full working code, which includes all the import statements. Otherwise, people are simply going to move on to another question that is easier and more convenient to solve.

Comment: As you have already identified, this has little to do with `make_column_transformer`, just that you can't use a feature whose values are lists.  How do you want a model to treat those lists?  Can you just unpack them into separate features (are they all the same length?)?

Comment: @Ananda I cannot offer a `X_train` sample because I'm having problem transforming my data before spiting my train and test data. My issue is on the transformation step.

Comment: @BenReiniger, My model is receiving 4 columns: 2 text columns, 1 number column (int) and on column is a object column type. I need to scale this last column to use in my classification. I cannot separate in columns because there would be 1272 columns, (they are not the same size). I identify the problem as the format that I'm entering in `make_column_transformer` , so I would like to know with anyone used a object column type in a `MinMaxScaler` step in sklearn.